# How do you receive SMS messages from Nexmo using rails Nexmo gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Rails 3.2.8 and considering using neximo.  The neximo gem does not seem to provide methods to receive SMS messages.  How do receive the SMS messages?  Do I create an controller with action to respond to GET? I am relatively new to rails, an looking for pointers on the approach to take.

1. how do I setup my route
2. I assume I do not need to render anything once I get the message, so I do not need the template, so I do I bypass the rendering?

Any pointer or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Well it looks like you'd want to use the [Ruby library built for Nexmo](https://github.com/timcraft/nexmo).

Essentially what you'd do is put this sample code:

```
nexmo = Nexmo::Client.new('...API KEY...', '...API SECRET...')

response = nexmo.send_message({
  from: 'RUBY',
  to: '...NUMBER...',
  text: 'Hello world'
})

if response.success?
  puts "Sent message: #{response.message_id}"
elsif response.failure?
  raise response.error
end
```

..inside an action in your controller. Let's say it's your `TextsController`, and you put it under the `create` action. So in your `config/routes.rb`, put something like:

`match "/sendtext" => "texts#create"`

Then, you just hit `mydomain.com/sendtext` and the command should fire.

Comment: Thank you, I did see the gem, but it does not provide recieve_message method.  How do I write the receive message method?

Comment: As Nexmo points out in the link Tim provided, you set up a url for Nexmo to send a get request to when you've received an SMS. There will be no "receive message method" -- basically what happens is that you tell Nexmo to hit a certain URL, and Nexmo will hit that url each time it receives a text. For example, with the above code, if you set up Nexmo to hit `mydomain.com/sendtext`, it'll send out a text message when you text Nexmo.

Comment: This URL is most likely going to be configured on your account settings for Nexmo on Nexmo's site.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, it is easy. First, generate controller, let say you call controller 'foo'

```
rails generate controller foo
```

in foo_controller.rb add the following:

```
class SmsesController < ApplicationController
  def getmessage
    text_from_phone_no = params[:msisdn]
    text_body = params[:text]
    # here you can extract more values from parameters as described in nexmo docs.

    render :nothing => true # this will supply the needed http 200 OK
  end
end
```

In routes.rb add the following:

> get "foo/getessage"

then in Nexmo, specify the URL for receiving messages as:

> your-domain.com/foo/getmessage.com

That is it you are done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's some kind of helper in the Ruby library to decode the response, but an incoming message is simply a HTTP GET or POST to whatever URL you configure for the number (in the Nexmo dashboard).

Here's the [documentation for incoming messages](http://nexmo.com/documentation/index.html#mo).

(*Disclaimer: I do a bit of developer evangelism for Nexmo.*)

Comment: So Tim, so the username and password are optional, how do you set these options?